# I want to calculate 2 input fields and display (print) it to the <p> tag

Tags: javascript, html

Hi friends (Gurus) I would be very glad if someone helps me out. Thank you great people. You always help. Any further tips or explanation would be appreciated.

```
<script>
function cal() {
    var firstNumber = document.getElementById("first").value;
    var secondNumber = document.getElementById("second").value;
    var total = firstNumber + secondNumber;
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=total;
}

function ca4l2() {
    var firstNumber = document.getElementById("first").value;
    var secondNumber = document.getElementById("second").value;
    var total = firstNumber + secondNumber;
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=total;
}
</script>


    <input type="number" id="first" onKeyPress="cal()"> +
    <input type="number" id="second" onKeyPress="cal2()">
    <p id="display"></p
```

Comment: The values read from HTML are **string** and **+** in this case is used as **string concatenation** operator. Convert them to Number. Ex: `var firstNumber = +document.getElementById("first").value;
var secondNumber = +document.getElementById("second").value;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/89jgucqd/)**

**HTML:**

```
<input type="number" id="first"> +
<input type="number" id="second">
<button id="btn">
  Calculate
</button>
<p id="display"></p>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var first = document.getElementById('first'),
  second = document.getElementById('second'),
  btn = document.getElementById('btn'),
  display = document.getElementById('display');

btn.addEventListener(
  "click", CalNum, false);

function CalNum() {
  display.innerHTML = parseInt(first.value) + parseInt(second.value);
}
```

> As requested from OP, this is another example of how to calculate
>   numbers without using a button to fire the function.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="number" id="first"> +
<input type="number" id="second">
<p id="display"></p>
```

**CSS**

```
#display {
  animation: OpacityBlink 1s linear infinite;
  /*You need to use -webkit- and all other properties for this transition to work on all browsers.*/
}

@keyframes OpacityBlink {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var first = document.getElementById('first'),
  second = document.getElementById('second'),
  display = document.getElementById('display');

first.addEventListener(
  "keyup", CalNum, false); //assigns the keyup event listener

second.addEventListener(
  "keyup", CalNum, false); //assigns the keyup event listener

function CalNum() {
  if (first.value === "" || second.value === "") {
    display.innerHTML = "Calculating.."; //if inputs value is empty display this string
  } else {
    display.style.animation = "none"; // stops the css3 animation
    display.innerHTML = parseInt(first.value) + parseInt(second.value); //displays the final result
  }
}

/* Please note that this only work if the user uses his keyboard to type the numbers. The CalNum function only fires if the event detects keyup, otherwise nothing will happen. You can always add another event listener for mouse clicks as well. */
```

Comment: Wow you are great guru!
How I wish you could be my brother or best friend.
Thank you very much. I have even understood one or two stuffs I never thought of.
Hope to talk to you soon!

Comment: what about if I don't wanna use button. I want it to calculate automatically as I type into the input field. 
Would be very appreciated if you help me this time round, too.
Thanks, my guru!

Answer (score 0):

Change to this,

```
var total = parseInt(firstNumber) + parseInt(secondNumber);
```

if the number is decimal, then,

```
var total = parseFloat(firstNumber) + parseFloat(secondNumber);
```